# Make DIV scroll with page without using pos:fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a div on the LHS of my page and I want it to scroll with the page, using position:fixed works fine but once I decrease the width of the browser window, the div hovers above the other elements on the page and gets in the way. This is obviously a result of the pos:fixed.

Can I make the div scroll with the page without having to use pos:fixed? With JS perhaps?
Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    #scrollerDiv{
        position: fixed;
        right:100px;
        top:238px;
        padding: 10px;
        width:48px;
        height:48px;
    }
```

Comment: A [jsBin](http://www.jsbin.com) mocking your DOM would be great. ;-)

Comment: Yes its possible. you can use jquery's `animate()` function for this.

Comment: Cheers Jai,  could you point me towards an example perhaps?

Comment: you can use absolute positioning with jQuery to recalculate the top and right positions when scrolling

Comment: @Daft just posted an answer along with an fiddle example.

Comment: @Daft How you would like to have when there is less width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 $(function(){ //<-----------------------doc ready
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('.scroll').css({
         top: scrollPos
      });
   }).scroll();
});
```

[For this i have made a fiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/24vaB/)